# Can't click buttons under a View acting as an overlay

Tags: android, overlay

I'm working on an app which has a View overlayed on the screen to act as a colour tint on the screen. I've got the view to come up in the colour I want and I can see buttons behind it.. the problem is I can't click them! :(

**Here's what the app has achieved on the screen (this is how I want it to look):**

[image: Notice the yellow tinge]

**My code:**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class OverlayService extends Service {
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View filter;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    filter = new View(this); // Create a new view
    float alpha = (float) 0.8; // Create alpha variable
    filter.setAlpha(alpha); // Set alpha (this doesn't seem to do anything)
    filter.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); // Set the background colour to yellow
    filter.getBackground().setAlpha(80); // Set the background's alpha (this is the call that works!)

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(filter, params);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (filter != null) windowManager.removeView(filter); // If the filter exists, remove it
  }

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure, but have you already tried to override 'onInterceptTouchEvent' to return false for the 'filter'-view?

Comment: In the layoutparams,  you should include "FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE".

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev The View (superclass) doesn't have a method called `onInterceptTouchEvent`.

Comment: @DeeV brilliant fixed! Thank you!

Comment: This is not working marshmallow

Comment: @Anilgangwar Take a look at this article: http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/07/android-m-begins-locking-down-floating-apps-requires-users-to-grant-special-permission-to-draw-on-other-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed by changing the WindowManager layout params to:**

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, // This line changed!
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Thanks to @DeeV :)

Comment: On a new AVD I've created the right hand side of the overlay is cut off, this was fixed by changing the first parameter to be `WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.